# how to enable ZTS on PHP?

Tags: php, linux

i try to install pthreads with (pecl install pthreads-beta) and get this error

checking checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled

know anyone how to install ?

Comment: Zend Thread Safety info can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782860/how-to-install-php-pthreads-extension-on-ubuntu

Comment: You need to recompile php with zts enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn them on, pass the `--enable-debug` and `--enable-maintainer-zts` options to configure, along with whatever options you typically use

Comment: If '--enable-debug' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf --enable-debug

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, you have to download the php source and compile it yourself.