# how to install pthread in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04

I have been strugling for hours on how to install [pthread](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) in my ubuntu server to allow php threading.
Please help me.

Comment: Related: [How to install PHP pthreads extension on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15782860)

Answer (score 4):

### HOW TO INSTALL IN LINUX SYSTEM'S:

The following instructions will result in an isolated installation of PHP that does not affect your current installation.

1) Checkout PHP sources into a new directory on your system

```
cd /usr/src
git clone https://github.com/php/php-src
cd php-src
```

1a) Optionally checkout a specific version of PHP

```
git checkout PHP-5.6
```

2) Download the pthreads sources to the build directory (/ext)

```
cd ext
git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads
cd ../
```

3) Configure new isolated PHP installation

```
./buildconf --force
./configure --prefix=/opt/php-zts \
            --bindir=/opt/php-zts/bin \
            --with-config-file-dir=/opt/php-zts \
            --with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/php-zts/modules.d/ \
            --enable-pthreads=shared \
            --with-curl=shared,/usr \
            --with-zlib \
            --with-libxml2 \
            --enable-simplexml \
            --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
            --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
            --enable-gd-native-ttf \
            --with-mysqli \
            --enable-shared \
            --enable-maintainer-zts \
            --enable-sockets \
            --with-curl=shared \
            --enable-mbstring
make -j8
make install
echo "extension=pthreads.so" > /opt/php-zts/modules.d/pthreads.ini
```

The configure command used here will result in a fairly standard installation with a sensible set of modules. If the build process fails, you should be able to resolve errors by installing developement packages, for example should the curl module fail to configure or build then

```
yum install curl-devel
```

Or the equivalent for your system should resolve the error, allowing the build to continue.

4) Symlink some useful things in /opt/php-zts/bin to /usr/local/bin

```
ln -s /opt/php-zts/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php-zts
ln -s /opt/php-zts/bin/phpize /usr/local/bin/phpize-zts
ln -s /opt/php-zts/bin/php-config /usr/local/bin/php-config-zts
ln -s /opt/php-zts/bin/php-cgi /usr/local/bin/php-cgi-zts
ln -s /opt/php-zts/bin/phpdbg /usr/local/bin/phpdbg-zts
```

At this point you have a working installation of PHP (version of your chosen branch or master if none) with pthreads available.

### BUILDING MODULES FOR USE WITH ISOLATED INSTALLATION:

The procedure for building modules is as follows (APCu used for example):

```
cd /usr/src
git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/acpu
cd apcu
phpize-zts
./configure --with-php-config=php-config-zts
make -j8
make install
echo "extension=apcu.so" > /opt/php-zts/modules.d/apcu.ini
```

You must be sure to pass the correct php-config path when building modules since by default your system installation of PHP will be detected.

*All blockquoted commands are ok for copypasta.*

Comment: i followed this tutorial before, but it gives me an error on the second command 'No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pthread"
install failed'

Comment: I have the same problem ... I notice that this is the same installation way as on http://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php but it not works!

Comment: Joe's [latest (excellent) work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019636/how-to-install-pthreads-on-a-phpfarm-php-installation#answer-23020481) intended to solve this scenario

Comment: This tutorial is really helpful, but I followed all of the steps and received no errors, but I am still running my old version of PHP, I am not sure how to activate the new version. Is there something I have to do to activate the new version of PHP?

Comment: @KevinWeber try php-zts