# PHP: Install bcmath mdoule to specific version of php

Tags: php, bcmath

I have 2 versions of php5.6 installed in my Ubuntu16.0.4. One is ZTS(Zend Thread Safety) enabled and another does not have zts. I want to install bcmath module to php-zts version. I used "apt install php5.6-bcmath" to install the module. Installation was successful, however by default the module is enabled only for php which doesnt have zts. How can I install it to my php-zts version. I tried enabling bcmath to the zts version but didnt workout.

Can any one help me on this pls.

PS: Default version enabled is php-zts.

Comment: how did you install both version? Source or via `apt`?
And how did you enabled it on php-zts?

Comment: I used Source. Here is the reference is used: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033191/how-to-install-pthread-in-ubuntu-12-10/50342973

And for enabling I used sudo a2enmod and updated the alternatives

Comment: So i think you have to compile php withi bcmath module. There is section `BUILDING MODULES FOR USE WITH ISOLATED INSTALLATION` on link you sent.

Comment: I tried that. It didnt work for me. Not sure where I'm missing out.