# failure while trying to install PHP threads via pecl

Tags: php, multithreading, installation

I'm trying to install PHP thread extension, which is oficially released via PECL:

```
root@tomasz-lenovo-ideapad-Y530:/tmp/pear/temp# pecl install pthreads
downloading pthreads-0.0.45.tgz ...
Starting to download pthreads-0.0.45.tgz (63,703 bytes)
................done: 63,703 bytes
35 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root322FWy/pthreads-0.0.45
running: /tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable Threading API... yes, shared
checking checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure' failed
```

The `/tmp/pear/temp/` directory exists, but `/tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/` doesn't. Anyone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the relevant error:

configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled

You should recompile/ install a zts enabled php version to use this module.

Comment: it' a shame that you have to recompile PHP locally to support multithreading :( I guess I have to forget about debian packages from this moment on (if I have to compile it manually)?

Comment: There is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782860/how-to-install-php-pthreads-extension-on-ubuntu maybe the responses help a bit.